# Duplicate AMI creation from scheduled lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have followed this [tutorial](http://powerupcloud.azurewebsites.net/2016/10/15/serverless-automate-ami-creation-and-deletion-using-aws-lambda/) and implemented the lambda functions for creating and deleting amis.

I have scheduled cron to run every day midnight using

```
cron(30 18 ? * MON-FRI *)
```

The creation of the AMI is working fine, however the issue is that for each instance it is creating multiple amis on a single date.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: This sounds like the Lambda function is failing and being retried.

Comment: Check the maximum execution time configured for the Lambda function then check the CloudWatch Logs for recent invocations. Did the Lambda timeout (and hence was retried)?

Comment: But image is getting created successfully